# Directional Differentiability follows from Multivariate Differentiability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

**The Exercise:** "Suppose that a function $f: R^n \to R^m$ is differentiable at $x \in R^n$. Show that the directional derivative of $f$ in any direction $v\in R^n$ at $x$ exists and $D_vf(x)=Df(x)(v)$"

Right now, I'm just working on the first part of the problem, showing that the directional derivative exists in any direction. I remember my professor telling us that this was the case, but I do not remember if/how he proved it.

Definition of differentiability at a point x:
There exists a linear transformation $T$ such that $lim_{h\to 0}\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Th\|/\|h\|=0$, where $h\to 0$ in $R^n$

Definition of directional differentiability at a point x in a direction v:
$D_vf(x)=lim_{t\to 0}(f(x+tv)-f(x))/t$

**My attempt:**
By definition of differentiability at a point, there exists a linear transformation $T$ such that $lim_{h\to 0}\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Th\|/\|h\|=0$, where $h\to 0$ in $R^n$. Consider $t\to 0$ in in $R$. Take any $v\in R^n$. $tv\to 0$ in $R^n$. i.e. $lim_{tv->0}\|f(x+tv)-f(x)-T(tv)\|/\|tv\|=0$ i.e. $lim_{t->0}\|f(x+tv)-f(x)-tT(v)\|/(t\|v\|)=0$. That's as far as I can get. Am I approaching this problem correctly? I'm not familiar with working with multivariable differentiability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Df(x)$ be the differential of $f$ at $x$: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{||f(x+h) - f(x)- Df(x) \cdot h||}{||h||}  = 0$$

Now let $v$ be a unit vector. Use $h = tv$ for $t \not= 0$: \begin{align*}\frac{||f(x+h) - f(x)- Df(x) \cdot h||}{||h||} &= \frac{||f(x+tv) - f(x) - Df(x) \cdot(tv)||}{||tv||} \\
&= \frac{||f(x+tv) - f(x) - tDf(x) \cdot v||}{|t|} \\ &= \left\| \frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t} - Df(x) \cdot v \right\|
\end{align*}
As $t \to 0$ so does $||h||$, and so $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \left\|\frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t} - Df(x) \cdot v \right\| = 0.$$ Thus $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t} = Df(x) \cdot v$.